# Can't start mariaDB Docker mounting specific dir

Tags: docker, mariadb

I have a very weird situation. When I start a mariaDB container using one dir, it gets stuck in "Initializing database":

```
$ docker run --name some-mariadb -v /mnt/data/msb/newsystem/db:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -p 3306:3306 mariadb:10.3
Initializing database
```

It stays there forever, it doesn't move forward and it doesn't die. Note that /mnt/data mounts /dev/sdb1 which although it is another hard disk, it's in the same computer and it's not a removable media or anything. I don't know if this is connected, it wouldn't make sense to me.

If on the other hand I start it on another dir, it all works:

```
$ docker run --name some-mariadb -v /home/msb/work/tmpdb:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -p 3306:3306 mariadb:10.3
Initializing database


PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:
....
```

This runs quite fast, within seconds. As far as I could check, both dirs have the same owner and permissions. My question is: why is it hanging in the first case? How could I debug that?

I'm new to docker and to mariaDB, although not new to mysql.
I was able to make it work using the dir I wanted, by following these steps:

1. create the container in the dir that works
2. stop the container (shut down the DB)
3. copy all files from the dir that I don't want to use to the dir that I want to use (preserving permissions and attributes obviously)
4. remove the container
5. create a new container using the dir that I want to use

Since the DB had already been initialized, it all worked fine, it started the DB as if it wasn't new. But I'm very intrigued as to why it didn't work using the desired dir right away, and I believe understanding that might help me understand how docker works better.

Comment: what type/filesystem was /mnt/data? What distro/version? What docker version?

Comment: Both /mnt/data and / are ext4. Docker is 18.06, host is running Lubuntu which I installed last week, so recent.